# Regex Include/Except, Begins/Ends

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering about how to type include/except for regex. 
For example to write a regex

All binary strings including the empty string vs.
All binary strings except empty string.

Also how would you write the regex for a string that begins and ends with 1?

Comment: Do you want 1hello1 to be matched as well?

Comment: If you excepted Steve's answer, that means you want 1hello1 to be matched as well, right?I'm just curious.

Comment: @JtheRocker Can you please remove my downvote: here was the requirement: "how would you write the regex for a string that begins and ends with 1?" where do you see anything wrong with my answer based off that question?

Comment: He mentioned, all binary strings except empty strings or with empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String regex = "[01]*";  //all binary Strings including empty string, * == 0 or more

String regex = "[01]+"; //all binary Strings except empty String, + == 1 or more

String regex = "^1(?:.*1)?$"; // a string that begins and ends with 1.
```

`(?:exp)` says group, but do not capture 
`^` beings with 
`$` ends with 
`?` 0 or 1 
`(?:.*1)?` 0 or 1 of any series of characters ending in 1

Comment: Your earlier answer ^1.*1$ also seemed to work. How come you changed it?

Comment: Forgot to account for the case of `"1"`.

Comment: Will your solution also match "1hello1"?

Comment: @JtheRocker Yes. The final String was not required to be binary.

Comment: Why would he want 1hello1?

Comment: He specified binary on the other two and not on this one and then accepted the answer...

Answer (score 1):

All binary strings (without leading zeroes) including the empty string:

```
str.matches("|1[01]*") // this uses an "OR" with nothing
```

All strings that begin and end in "1", including the edge case of just "1":

```
str.matches("1(.*1)?") // this must be a 1, optionally followed by anything ending in 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourText.matches("|1|^1[01]*1$"); //all binaries with empty string
```

And,

```
yourText.matches("1|^1[01]*1$"); //all binaries except empty string
```

Comment: what about just "1"? It starts and ends in "1". also ^ and $ are not neeeded with matches() - they are implied because matches() must match the *whole* input

Comment: ^1 is for start and 1$ for end

Comment: 1001 is valid 1000 is not

Comment: He's saying your regex fails to match the string `"1"`.

Comment: And OP said strict binary

Comment: your regex does not match "1"

Comment: It would work for 1 or 101? And it won't for 10 or 100? So, where is the problem?

Comment: @JtheRocker forgot how java regex worked with match.  your answer is fine and I removed my downvote...

Comment: And why Am I being down voted here again? Whoever down voted, please specify your reason.